# From which email address does MFMailComposeViewController sends the message in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using inbuilt framework of iPhone sdk to send an email.

So is there any way to test this functionality on iPhone simulator.

Also the composer shows only TO, CC, BCC but not FROM, so what email id does it use to send an email to the specified recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails sent from apps other than Mail use the default mail account (configured in the Settings app).